# Sound is not playing with MediaPlugin on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms project I'm using the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) version 0.9.0 (Android target 28) to play sounds, but unfortunately it's not working.

There are no errors, the player appears in the notification window, but there is no sound.

My Android code:

```
private readonly string[] _permissions = {
        Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState,
        Manifest.Permission.AccessNetworkState,
        Manifest.Permission.Internet,
        Manifest.Permission.ForegroundService,
        Manifest.Permission.WakeLock,
        Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
        Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
    };

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        RequestPermissions(_permissions, 0);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        MediaManager.CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();

    }
   public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

portable version code:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("http://muziksiz.merakla.com/ama/ama20.mp3");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no sound, but the playback notification appears.

Comment: The version of the plugin is  4.x.x , and which didn't support playing voice any more  .If you want to play online voice , check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42008/audio-streaming-on-ios-and-android .